# Copy file conditionally from multiple folders to multiple folders

Tags: .net, powershell

I need a script that allows me to drop a file in any of 4 folders within a watched folder, and copy that file to two folders based on the folder it was dropped in.

> WATCHED FOLDER: C:\Users\Username\Desktop\PS DROP FOLDERS
>
> C:\Users\Username\Desktop\PS DROP FOLDERS\18x23
>   
> copy to C:\Users\Username\Desktop\IJET RIP FOLDERS\LARGE 18x23
>   
> copy to C:\Users\Username\Desktop\STE RIP - HR FOLDERS\LARGE 16x20-18x23
>
> C:\Users\Username\Desktop\PS DROP FOLDERS\LARGE
>   
> copy to C:\Users\Username\Desktop\IJET RIP FOLDERS\LARGE 16x20
>   
> copy to C:\Users\Username\Desktop\STE RIP - HR FOLDERS\LARGE 16x20-18x23
>
> C:\Users\Username\Desktop\PS DROP FOLDERS\MANUAL
>   
> copy to C:\Users\Username\Desktop\IJET RIP FOLDERS\MANUAL 15x15
>   
> copy to C:\Users\Username\Desktop\STE RIP - HR FOLDERS\MANUAL 15x15
>
> C:\Users\Username\Desktop\PS DROP FOLDERS\SMALL
>   
> copy to C:\Users\Username\Desktop\IJET RIP FOLDERS\SMALL 16x20
>   
> copy to C:\Users\Username\Desktop\STE RIP - HR FOLDERS\SMALL 16x20

Below is the code I currently have for the watched folder part (taken from another Q/A), but I can't figure out the logic to copy to to multiple folders conditionally. Seems like there's a much better way than IF statements.

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\PS DROP FOLDERS"
$watcher.Filter = "*.ps"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER A EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = {

HELP INQUIRY CODE HERE

}
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED + SET CHECK FREQUENCY  
$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
### $changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
### $deleted = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
### $renamed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Sorry for the lack of skill. I don't expect a solution, but some guidance would be nice. Thank you.

P.S. This is to route files to hot folders of a RIP program for two different imaging systems.

Comment: That looks like a good starting template, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I would recommend running `Get-Help about_Switch` and using the `Switch` command to define cases and actions. Then for cases maybe something like `{(split-path $_.directory -leaf) -eq '18x23'}{$_|Copy-Item 'C:\PathA';$_|Copy-Item 'C:\PathB'}`

Comment: Thank you! You really pointed me in the right direction. Working code below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to TheMadTechnician I've come up with a solution using the `switch` command. Hope this helps someone else too.

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\PS DROP FOLDERS"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.ps"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER A EVENT IS DETECTED
       $action = { 
                   #GET NAME OF PARENT DIRECTORY FOR SWITCH AND OUTPUT VALUES IN CONSOLE
                   $item = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                   $path = Split-Path (Split-Path $item -Parent) -leaf
                   Write-Host "item : " $item
                   Write-Host "path : " $path

      switch ($path)
    { 
        "LARGE" {
                   $destination = @("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\IJET RIP FOLDERS\LARGE 16x20","C:\Users\Username\Desktop\STE RIP - HR FOLDERS\LARGE 16x20-18x23")

                   foreach ($dir in $destination)
                   {
                   Copy-Item -Path $item -Destination $dir
                   }
                } 
        "SMALL" {
                   $destination = @("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\IJET RIP FOLDERS\SMALL 16x20","C:\Users\Username\Desktop\STE RIP - HR FOLDERS\SMALL 16x20")

                   foreach ($dir in $destination)
                   {
                   Copy-Item -Path $item -Destination $dir
                   }
                }
        "MANUAL" {
                   $destination = @("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\IJET RIP FOLDERS\MANUAL 15x15","C:\Users\Username\Desktop\STE RIP - HR FOLDERS\MANUAL 15x15")

                   foreach ($dir in $destination)
                   {
                   Copy-Item -Path $item -Destination $dir
                   }
                }
        "18x23" {
                   $destination = @("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\IJET RIP FOLDERS\LARGE 18x23","C:\Users\Username\Desktop\STE RIP - HR FOLDERS\LARGE 16x20-18x23")

                   foreach ($dir in $destination)
                   {
                   Copy-Item -Path $item -Destination $dir
                 }
              }
            }
          }
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED + SET CHECK FREQUENCY  
    $created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
### $changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
### $deleted = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
### $renamed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```